# Rerunning a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my android game, I am spawning a separate thread to play a sound of `soundpool` class. Every time I have to play the sound I have to create a new thread and execute `thread.start()`. Is it possible to create thread once and reuse ? I want to do this so that I can avoid the overhead of spawning a lot of threads.

Comment: nope, once a `Thread` has terminated, you need to create a new `Thread` to re-run the `Runnable` logic

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create thread once and reuse ?

Its not possible.

Possible solution is to use thread pool of fixed size (depends on your requirement) and keep on reusing it by submitting your runnable tasks to the thread pool.

Determining the perfect size of thread pool is important, too less will have the similar problem and too high will have performance issues. So you need to do some benchmarking to determine the same. A better idea is to make it configurable and monitor it.

You may want to look [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) in java to learn about Thread pools.

Comment: Actually, it is possible. If you create a Thread with its own Looper and Handler and start it, it will wait for messages and runnables and execute them as they arrive.

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use "ThreadPoolExecuter"..

this is a good example:

https://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/util/UserTask.java

Answer (score 2):

You can create one infinite thread that will play your sound every time you trigger it to do so, using `synchronized`, `wait` and `notify` commands.

```
class InfininteTriggerableThread extends Thread {


    private volatile boolean paused = true;
    private final Object pauseObject = new Object();


    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            while(true){
                while (paused) {
                    synchronized(pauseObject) {
                        pauseObject.wait();
                    }
                }
                // do your action here
                paused = true;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    }



    // trigger method
    public void trigger(){
        paused = false;
        synchronized(pauseObject) {
            pauseObject.notify();
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: will that create less overhead ?

Comment: this will create just 1 thread for all time. Most of time it will be in idle state

Comment: so when `pauseObject.wait()` is run the `while` loop stops executing and thread waits(sleeps) ? Also, how to initiate trigger ?

Comment: Will `InfininteTriggerableThread k = new InfininteTriggerableThread(); k.trigger();` do ?

Comment: First you need to start it once as usual thread by `start` and every time you want to trigger an action, call `trigger`. You even can pass a sound you need to play as a parameter if there are many sounds in your app

Comment: yes, `while(true)` loop will pause  until synchronized object `pauseObject`  gets notification by `notify` method, which you invoke in `trigger` method. This technique is based on Java thread synchronization

Comment: if you're wondering if processor will do unnecessary work running while(true) and while(pause) loops -- no, it won't. Thread will pause until synchronized object becomes available

Comment: so when `notify()` is run where the execution starts ? inside `while(paused)` ?

Comment: yes, when you call `notify` after calling `wait`, object will be notified synchronized and thread will quit `synchronized` block. It will quit `while(paused)` and continue executing as I show by comments in the code.

Comment: actually, `while(paused)` is not needed here, you can use `if(paused)` instead, but `while` is traditional and more robust.

Comment: I cannot use this method in case of implementing runnable ... right ? `class InfininteTriggerableThread implements Runnable`

Comment: Runnable has just one abstract method `run()` so yes, any `Thread` implements `Runnable` as well at this class. By the way, you can name it as you want, what I show is just a working sketch.

Comment: I think I created some confusion. By method I meant technique. Let me re-ask. Can I use this technique on Runnable instead of thread ?

Comment: I understand that I can name the class whatever I want.

Comment: I suppose you can, but I never tried to. You should have a try.

Comment: I did try but the thread which receives this runnable does not show up `trigger` method.

Comment: One more question I have. What happens when the two task are in quick succession ? Will the second task quequed or it will be lost if it appears before the first is finished ?

Comment: in this solution, second task will be lost

Comment: Is there a way to queue it in this solution ?

Comment: of course, just modify trigger method so if paused == true, it will set paused to false and call notify, if paused == false, add some object that it receives as parameter (e.g. your sound), into a queue. So in run() method it should look at the queue and play every sound until queue  becomes empty.

Comment: I've found another way of running infinite thread so that runnables can be received and executed by it one by one. Method is to run `Looper.prepare()`, then create a handler, then run `Looper.loop()` in this new thread--so runnables could be sent to this particular handler and executed in thread to which it is attached without loss. Tomorrow I will come back with example (I'm also interested in this topic)

Answer (score 1):

As I promised before, I tested thread that uses `Looper` to run infinitely and can accept `Runnable`s to execute them one by one.

```
// create a custom Thread class
class ThreadWorking extends Thread {

    public volatile Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        // between Looper.prepare() and Looper.loop() we need to create a handler
        // which will receive messages and runnables for this thread
        Looper.prepare();
        handler = new Handler();
        Looper.loop();
    }
};

// then create new thread and start it
final ThreadWorking threadWorking = new ThreadWorking();
threadWorking.start();
Log.println(Log.DEBUG, "thread test", "New thread started");
```

Now the new Thread is looping and can receive `Message`s and `Runnable`s by its `Handler`. They will be stored in internal queue and executed one after another in this particular thread. To test, I send `Runnable` on button click:

```
threadWorking.handler.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
             Log.println(Log.DEBUG, "thread test", "Executed: " + System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
             Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    }
});
```

After I launched an app and clicked the button several times quickly, log shows this:

```
04-09 16:21:56.599: D/thread test(19264): New thread started
04-09 16:21:59.569: D/thread test(19264): Executed: 1397046119
04-09 16:22:01.569: D/thread test(19264): Executed: 1397046121
04-09 16:22:03.569: D/thread test(19264): Executed: 1397046123
04-09 16:22:05.569: D/thread test(19264): Executed: 1397046125
04-09 16:22:07.569: D/thread test(19264): Executed: 1397046127
04-09 16:22:09.569: D/thread test(19264): Executed: 1397046129
```

So everything is working correctly as expected, without freezing UI or creating additional threads.

Comment: i underdtand that this new thread will be in infinite loop till the loop is stopped. what happens when this looper does not receives new runnables after executing a few. will it lie low without consuming resources or it will affect performance ?

Comment: looking in Android implementation of Looper class which differs from Java Looper, I discovered that loop() method just starts infinite `for (;;)` loop in which queue is asked for new messages. Sincerely, I don't know how it may affect performance, because I'm not so deep in Dalvik JVM internal procedures and optimizations. But I think it should work better than creating a new thread every time--just because all operations for creating a new thread are made in UI thread and thus affect it much worse.

Comment: infinite for loop will consume resources unless it has implementation similar to your previous answer where u used notify and wait.

Comment: for sure! but it is much easier to implement since you don't need to design internal mechanism of task queue.

Comment: I think we can use notify and wait in this example to get best of both worlds.