# Non blocking looper class in android

Tags: android, multithreading

`Looper` class in android blocks the thread. It is used to execute tasks as and when arrived.
In my case the tasks will be delivered to the looper thread intermittently, there will be time gap between the tasks. The time gap is not fixed, it changes as per user interaction. I do not want the infinite loop of the looper class to run when there is not task, since this will consume resources. Is there a way such that the thread executes the task as and when it arrives without blocking the thread ?

Comment: What would the thread do if not executing the task?

Comment: Looper puts a task to the queue of given thread, task is started after executing all previous tasks in the queue. What do you mean by "blocking the thread"?

Comment: @MartinJames please read the edited question

Comment: @Salauyou looper.loop() runs an infinite for loop in order to execute the task.

Comment: @user3293494 of course, that's is purpose of looper itself :) Alternative option can be creating separate thread for every task or using _wait/notify pattern_.

Comment: could you please elaborate on " wait/notify pattern"

Comment: @user3293494 http://stackoverflow.com/a/22911513/3459206

Comment: @Salauyou dont u think if there are additional infinite loops that will affect the performance of UI thread ?

Comment: In my projects, everything is okay. You should try and test all options. StackOverflow community will be very greatful if you make such tests and provide results--that will show your ability in answering the questions, not just asking.

Comment: could anybody plz explain negative vote

Comment: It was not me who gave negative vote, but I believe the reason is because users with lots of reputation are sparing their time to give good, rational, well explained answers to your question on a very simple subject and you keep fighting with them that it will consume your CPU.

Comment: but am i wrong on that ? could you plz confirm.

Comment: Look, threads that are blocked on a producer-consumer queue, (such as the looper construct), because the queue is empty do not use any CPU.  None.  Not one cycle, nothing, nada.  When an item is posted to the queue, the OS makes the thread ready again and, when it runs, it runs once round your 'infinite loop' and then gets blocked again until another item gets posted.  If no item gets posted for an hour, the thread will use no CPU cycles at all for an hour because execution has been removed from it for that hour.  BLOCKING IS NOT A BAD THING.

Comment: @MartinJames thanks for reply, I really appreciate it. could you please guide me to resources where I can study these concepts in detail. I am clueless what term to search for.

Answer (score 2):

No.
That's the idea and function for a looper. It holds the thread to be ready to dispatch new tasks (`Runnable`) when available.

If you want your thread to do some other function, you need to send the `Runnable` to the thread via the looper.

Comment: what if there is a time gap between the tasks ?

Comment: ..then the thread does nothing.  There is nothing to do, so it does nothing.  It's blocked on the looper queue until there is something to do.

Answer (score 1):

"*I do not want the infinite loop of the looper class to run when there is not task, since this will consume resources*".

Which resources do you care of? Blocked thread does not consume CPU time, it only consumes memory. The only way to save that memory is to finish the thread (return from its `run()` method). If you have small number of Looper threads, then there is nothing to worry about. If you have large number of threads, then use [java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead of all your looper threads. If you care about sequential execution you enjoyed with looper threads, use `SerialExecutor` described in [java.util.concurrent.Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html).

Comment: could you plz explain why it will not consume cpu time ?

Comment: See, for example, http://habrahabr.ru/post/124794/ . Or https://www.google.ru/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=blocking+thread+consume+cpu+time

Comment: i read the posts on google search, they are not refering to infinite for loops when they are talking about blocked threads. Apparently, in java thread state is blocked if it is waiting for a monitor lock.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html

Comment: Infinte loop will be in a runnable state as per above url

Comment: i just ran an infinite for loop in a separate thread in my application. It slows down the application a great deal, clearly it consumes cpu time.

Comment: OK, now run your infinite loop with a Sleep(1000) call in it, see what happens to app speed, (nothing).

Comment: @MartinJames what happens when there is nothing inside the loop ? does it consume cpu in that case ?

Comment: Sure, if the loop does not get optimized out.

Comment: So is the infinite for loop in the looper class is optimized ? http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-looper-and-toast-from.html